# Converting spanish date into python pandas datetime object with locale setting

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've got 2 questions:

1. How can I convert a Spanish datetime 'ago122010' into 2010-08-12 using **pandas**. Is the format used in **strptime** correct?

I've tried the following:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES.utf8')

from datetime import datetime as dt

df['date'] = dt.strptime(df['date'], '%b%d%Y')
df['date'] = df['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: unsupported locale setting
```

2. how can I convert this '20100812' to a datetime using **pandas**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think the issue is with the locale used. Also, check your formatting.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'es_ES.UTF-8')

from datetime import datetime as dt
datetime_object = dt.strptime('20100812', '%Y%m%d')
datetime_object
```

**Output:**

```
datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 12, 0, 0)
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Tried few more examples.

```
# read a spanish datetime format
datetime_object = dt.strptime('martes 12 julio 2016', '%A %d %B %Y')
print(datetime_object.strftime("%B"))
print(datetime_object)

# Change the locale to swede and print the month
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "sv_SE")  
print(datetime_object.strftime("%B"))
```

**Output:**

```
julio
2016-07-12 00:00:00
Juli
```

Edited to incorporate the specific details you wanted:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'es_ES.UTF-8')

from datetime import datetime as dt

datetime_object = dt.strptime('ago122010', '%b%d%Y')
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'en_US.UTF-8')
print(datetime_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

**Output**

2010-08-12

Comment: First, Is there another way of doing this without using **locale**? And Second, I wasn't able to achive this: transform 'ago122010' into 2010-08-12. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is ago in the datetime? Is it Spanish?

Comment: 'ago' (aug in english) is short for 'agosto' (august) a month in spanish. Haven't been able to transform it to datetime.