# spanish datetime return NaT

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a date column with the format `19 dic 2020 23:59` (spanish date)
and I want to convert it into a `datetime` type.

```py
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format='%d %b %Y %H:%M', errors = "coerce")
```

After running the code column is the right type `datetime` but it only contains NaT values.

what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: what is 'dic' should that be 'dec'?

Comment: @adirabargil Rather country-specific datetime format. This should be specified in the question. Ignacio: Please do not post images of code/data/error messages. Post the text directly here on SO.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is an error that is associated with pandas' function not supporting other locales such as `es_ES` as in your case. I would recommend changing the locale or iterating as is described in these two answers. The first uses a locale change via `datetime` and the second recommends using substitution.

1. [Converting spanish date into python pandas datetime object with locale setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849150/converting-spanish-date-into-python-pandas-datetime-object-with-locale-setting)
2. [Pandas to datetime with German date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558706/pandas-to-datetime-with-german-date-format)

Comment: SO has the duplicate flag for a reason

Comment: for `%b`, the spanish month name abbreviation input must be e.g. `dic.`; notice the dot. this is neither a pandas nor a locale problem - even if you set the locale correctly, you still need to supply the correct input to strptime.

Answer (score 1):

*This is neither a pandas nor a locale problem.* For one, your `strptime` directive is slightly wrong, and second, your input just doesn't match `%b`. `pd.to_datetime` works fine if you set the correct locale, supply the correct input and set the correct format directive:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES')

import pandas as pd

s = '19 dic 2020 23:59'
print(pd.to_datetime(s.replace('dic', 'dic.'), format='%d %b %Y %H:%M'))
# 2020-12-19 23:59:00
```